# Jquery IE7 Id append issue

Tags: jquery, css

So I have following Jquery

```
    $j("a#Pinterest").html("<img src='/images/Social Media/pinterest.png'>");
```

And mark up is as follows ;

```
<a id="Pinterest"></a>
```

Which works fine, but the user has an option to add multiple  to one page, and I noticed that in IE7 only the first anchor gets the image attached and not the others. In all other browsers, they all get the image attached.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Are there multiple copies of "<a id="Pinterest"></a>" in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<a class="Pinterest"></a>
<a class="Pinterest"></a>
```

**JS**

```
$j("a.Pinterest").html("<img src='/images/Social Media/pinterest.png'>");
```

Id should be unique but you can use class for a group of elements using same class name.

Answer (score 6):

`id` must be unique on a html page. You can only use the same ID once. Use a `class` attribute instead.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was hinting at. :)